# How do you set up your JScript (NOT JScript.NET) development environment?

Tags: compiler-errors, javascript

In my environment, if I create a class in JScript syntax:

```
class test{

}
```

and then save it to a file named "test.js" and run it with wscript, I get a Microsoft JScript "Syntax error" at line 1.

However, if I simply, say, write a function:

```
  function getInput() {

   var wshell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
   wshell.Popup ("Do you want to continue?");

   return userInput
}

getInput()
```

and run it the same way, it works.

Hopefully, there is something fundamentally wrong with my class definition. If that is the case, I am excited to find out.

Answer (score 4):

JScript is just Microsoft's implementation of [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript)/ECMAScript. As such, it doesn't have classes, or any of the other things added to JScript.NET to make it kinda-sorta fit into .NET.

Ignore JScript.NET, and read up on [the WSH version of JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbxc2t98.aspx).